# Do smaller numbers of goldfish form pairs?

Tags: behavior, fish, socializing, pond, goldfish

I've been asking a lot of questions about goldfish, as I am preparing for a bigger pond.

I currently have three comets that I will move to  the bigger pond. The pond will be approx 350 L so there will be ample room for them. When the three fish were together, the smallest one was being pushed out of the way at feeding time, now this could be due to them needing more room. Since I moved the largest fish to his own pond, this has stopped.

I am wondering, with small numbers of goldfish, is it better to have an even number to reduce bullying or does it make no difference? I am wondering if they form friendship pairs? *(I am not referring to mating pairs, as I have no idea what sex these fish are, but if there is information abut mating pairs, this is also a good thing).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, goldfish do not "pair up" — not socially, and not even in breeding. Goldfish are okay in smaller numbers in aquariums, but in larger ponds, they'll do much better in schools.

If you are moving the fish to a new home, try to add them to their new home all at once. This will help avoid some of the territorial behaviors which can lead to aggression. And if you are introducing *new* fish to a group, it's sometimes helpful to move around any accessories or decorations you might have in the pond to break that *"this is my spot"* instinct.

The reference (below) talks about group spawning, but that schooling behavior applies to any type of social activity:

[Goldfish, Gregory Skomal](http://books.google.com/books?id=v5EnQah5bNEC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=do+goldfish+form+pairs&source=bl&ots=yrvygIK-Hd&sig=yS4NQiKq7ZFFaP4nhu_rejWQ64A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YK6DUrjAL4au2gXhxYCYDw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=do%20goldfish%20form%20pairs&f=false)